# OpenTok subscriber video showing black screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, opentok, tokbox

I'm working on app in which two users can make video calls.I'm using OpenTok iOS SDK 2.5 for this.My problem is some times subscriber video not showing correctly; it's showing a black screen. The call was active and we are getting audio. For `OTSubscriber` and `OTPublisher` settings `publishVideo` and `subscribeToVideo` are set to `YES`. What's the issue?

Comment: please provide code showing what you have tried yet, so others can see if there are problems with the implementation.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the implementation. TokBox itself stoping the video to improve call quality when the internet connection is poor.